# Android 6.0 Emulator missing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I've installed Android Studio 1.5.1 and everything relative to Android 6.0:

[image: SDK]

However, I can't create an emulator with Android 6.0

[image: System images]

How can I fix that?

Comment: If you go to "tools>android>AVD manager" then try to create a new virtual device, pick a phone (eg Nexus 6P), then go to the next screen, you should see a list of android versions (up to "N" not just "M").  You don't see that?

Comment: No, see screenshot #2 (Virtual Device Configuration). It's what I see after selecting any Nexus emulator.

Comment: On your computer's file system go to Android>Sdk>system-images.  You should see a directory for every system image that you have installed.  You're looking for version 23 (M).  If you don't see that then your first screenshot may be faulty -- what's shown may not be what's really on your drive.  Maybe something went wrong in the installation process???  edit: I have a Linux system. Your file system may look different (location of system images)

Comment: My `system-images` folder is empty... :(

Comment: My best guess is that something went wrong at installation and the system images didn't get copied where they need to be.  There's probably a more elegant way to fix this but I'd just re-install -- taking care to copy any application files you have to a safe place so they can't can't be over-written.

Comment: I've uninstalled/reinstalled through both SDK manager and Android Studio, still nothing.

Comment: I've just switched to Android 2.0 and everything is fine now.